# PHP multiple arraw selected from database

Tags: php, arrays, database, multiple-columns, dropdown

Hello please can anyone give idea for this?
I want data will selected when it match with their id but when i try this some data will not selected just display only how can I make it selected by their ID?
**In this array it work:**

```
[0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3
```

**In this array it won't work:**

```
[0] => 20 [1] => 21 [2] => 22 [3] => 23 [4] => 24
```

```php
$stat = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM department");
$stat2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM docprivacy WHERE doc_id = $id ORDER BY dep_id");   

$stat2->execute();

$array = array();

while ($row3 = $stat2->fetch()) {
    extract($row3);
 array_push($array, $row3['dep_id'] )    ; 
}

$stat->execute();
$i = 0 ;

while($row = $stat->fetch()){
    extract($row);
    while ( $i < count($array)) {
        # code...

     if ($row['d_id'] == $array[$i]){
       echo "<option value = '{$d_id}' selected>".$row['department']."</option>";
      }else{
        echo "<option value = '{$d_id}'>".$row['department']."</option>";
    }

    $i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: And where is the error?

Comment: your question is unclear please provide an example of data you are looking for and what you are actually getting.

Comment: what i want is i want selected department in dropdown when i run that some data will not select and just display only

Comment: andrew, please edit your question (rather than enhancing it in the comments)

Comment: Change `$d_id` to `$row['d_id']` (also don't hide code) post all relevant parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (in_array($row['d_id'], $array ))
  {
     echo "<option value = '{$row['d_id']}' selected>".$row['department']."</option>";
  }
else
  {
    echo "<option value = '{$row['d_id']}'>".$row['department']."</option>";
  }
```

Comment: Even this answer seems valid it is preferred to add explanation and not just the code

Comment: $stat result  store  to $array and $stat2  result get through while loop that time we check  department id  there in $array using in_array

Comment: i will explain with below example
 $array = array ("1","2","3");

$array1 = array ("1","4","5");


foreach($array1 as $arr)
{
  if(in_array($arr, $array ))
    {
      echo "same";
    }else{
      echo "notsame";
    }
}

Comment: I meant add explanation to your answer (edit it) to have it more then just code but also educational (and worth of up-vote)

Comment: Yes your answer is what I really needed and perfectly working thanksss!!

Answer (score 0):

The error I think is with this line

```
$i = 0 ;
```

After the first loop, the $i already more than the $array count. so it is not execute.
Move it to.

```
while($row = $stat->fetch()){
    extract($row);
    $i = 0 ;
```